# Use Lucene as Dbms

Tags: sql-server, lucene, database

In our project our data capacity is high (100Gb of data) and we use sql serve as dbms . 
unfortunately  full text search in sql server is rather disappointing so we're using lucene to search our data . but the problem is lucene needs to index data and so the capacity of holding both lucene index and our database would take too much disk space . 
so i was wondering can we put sql server aside and just use lucene ? is it stable enough for holding millions of records of data ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want full text search you need to have full text index, no matter where it's physically located.

But, since you have problems with space, I assume you used stored="true" in your schema fields.
Store it in db (preferably something other than MSSQL) and index it in Solr/Lucene.

Comment: right, the inverted index is rather cheap (often ~30% of the original size of the data)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/). It's lightning fast, based on Lucene and can function as a stand-alone db. Not to mention the maker likes to put it under all kind of stress.

Only "downside": it's commercial, so it's gonna cost ya :)